# How to save an image with Webcam.js?

Tags: javascript, webcam, webcam-capture, webcam.js

I want to save an image that is recently captured using the WebCam. I'm using Webcam.js, it returns an image in a string format. I want to save this image inside the local directory.

```
        // Capure and save Image
        var data = Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
           console.log('Image Save',typeof data_uri)
        });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a jpg image/video captured with webcam in the local hard drive with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882550/how-to-save-a-jpg-image-video-captured-with-webcam-in-the-local-hard-drive-with)

Comment: It's something different because the above question isn't related to Webcam.js

Answer (score 0):

there is a nice (deprecated) wordpress plugin WP_Snapcam which is based on webcam.js, here the code for saving the photo on server in PHP/JS:
[hier](https://github.com/nierdz/wp-snapcam/blob/master/wp-snapcam/public/class-wp-snapcam-widget.php)